# Showing the IL Code of a .net assembly?

Tags: c#

I try to decompile a .net assembly.
Currently I get the class- and typenames.
But how do I get the IL Code of the whole binary?

Comment: Are you interested in *modifying* the IL or just *reviewing* it?

Comment: Guess the correct question is "how do I get the IL code of the whole **assembly**" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Ildasm. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.100).aspx) is the documentation from MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the output:

```
ildasm /OUT=decompiled.il file
```

Need further help? Next time, try running `ildasm /?`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the assembly in ILDasm GUI. 
2) File -> Dump (Ctrl-D)
3) Choose options 
4) Save the IL file